# Is this the correct way to write a SQLAlchemy many-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Say I am creating a system where customers can order widgets. Each customer may order many widgets, and each widget may be ordered by many customers, so I need a link table to store the orders (where some additional information, like the quantity, can also be stored).

So far, I have come up with the following implementation:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Order(db.Model):
    customer_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("customer.id"), primary_key=True)
    widget_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("widget.id"), primary_key=True)

    customer = db.relationship("Customer", back_populates="orders")
    widget = db.relationship("Widget", back_populates="orders")

    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer)

class Customer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

    orders = db.relationship("Order", back_populates="customer",
        cascade="all, delete-orphan", lazy="dynamic")

class Widget(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)

    orders = db.relationship("Order", back_populates="widget",
        cascade="all, delete-orphan", lazy="dynamic")
```

Is this correct? Particularly, do I need the `customer` and `widget` attributes on `Order`, or could I do something with `backref` instead? (and if so, is there any advantage to using `back_populates` over `backref` or vice versa?)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: An advantage of using `back_populates=` could be that some (static) analyzers might not be able to deduce `Order.customer` etc., if using `backref=`.